# Hide all columns in an Excel table except a few chosen ones

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel table `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable")`. How can I hide all its columns except for the more interesting ones? Curretly my code was generated by recording a macro:

```
Columns("A:C").Hidden = True
Columns("F:G").Hidden = True
Columns("I:U").Hidden = True
Columns("W:X").Hidden = True
Columns("AA:AI").Hidden = True
Columns("AK:CQ").Hidden = True
```

Because the less important columns come and go or get rearranged, I'd like to refer to the columns by name rather than column letter. Something along the lines of:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns("#All").Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns("Email").Hidden = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns("User").Hidden = False
...
```

Comment: What do you mean with selected ones? Actual selected column on the sheet? Or are they always the same? If the latter, pls tell us which columns need to stay visible.

Comment: They are not selected in the literal sense. I mean chosen ones. There is no active selection in the sheet. I want to hide everything except, say columns named "Email", "User", "Country", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your edited question I think you looking for:

```
Sub Check()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    .Range("myTable").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    .Range("myTable[Email]").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    .Range("myTable[User]").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The required can be done easily with the following loop:

```
Sub hide()
Sub hide()
Dim column As Range
Dim Lastcolumn As Long
Lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
For Each column In ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Lastcolumn))
If column = "Unhide" Or column = "Unhide also" Then
column.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
column.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
Next
End Sub
```

For every column you would like not to be hidden you add another `or` statement with an updated name.

*Edited to negate the use of absolute columns and just use used range of columns instead.*

Comment: I don't like this solution much because here you use again some absolute column letters ("A:BB") which was exactly what I'm trying to avoid. As mentioned, column in the tabe come and go, or get rearranged.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. Therefore @JvdV solution is much more elegant. Mine could be updated to hide everything, but it would need a bunch of nested `if` statements to unhide the ones you want. I'll update my answer but I'll admit it is inferior.